# How do I take restore a back up of database in PostgreSQL 9.6 into PostgreSQL 12.2?

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to upgrade my database 
from PostgreSQL 9.6 to PostgreSQL 12.2
using pg_dump/pgrestore method.

I've already tried dumping data from older version using pg_dump12.
(As pgdump and pgrestore are compatible only with same major version)

Comment: And what is the error you get?

Comment: There is no error. But the process is also running.